# combining two while loops of python into one

Tags: python, while-loop

i need to combine my python codes which when the door is closed the PIR sensor will start to sense movement. when i combine these two files, it will run only the first while loop. it did not run to the next loop. can someone figure it out?

the first while loop:

```
#function for door closing
def door_open():
    print("Door Open")

# function for the door closing
def door_close():
    print("Door Close")

while True:
    if GPIO.input(door_sensor): # if door is opened
        if (sensorTrigger):
           door_open() # fire GA code
           sensorTrigger = False # make sure it doesn't fire again
        if not io.input(door_sensor): # if door is closed
            if not (sensorTrigger):
                door_close() # fire GA code
                sensorTrigger = True # make sure it doesn't fire again
```

second while loop:

```
Current_State  = 0
Previous_State = 0


# Loop until PIR output is 0
while GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR)==1:
   Current_State  = 0

print "  Ready"

while True :

  # Read PIR state
  Current_State = GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR)

  if Current_State==1 and Previous_State==0:
    # PIR is triggered
    print "  Motion detected!"
    # Record previous state
    Previous_State=1
  elif Current_State==0 and Previous_State==1:
    # PIR has returned to ready state
    print "  Ready"
    Previous_State=0

# Wait for 10 milliseconds
time.sleep(0.01)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print "  Quit"
  # Reset GPIO settings
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

---

i try to combine these two loops, but the result only the first loop is run

```
#function for door closing
def door_open():
    print("Door Open")

# function for the door closing
def door_close():
    print("Door Close")

while True:
    if GPIO.input(door_sensor): # if door is opened
        if (sensorTrigger):
           door_open() # fire GA code
           sensorTrigger = False # make sure it doesn't fire again
        if not io.input(door_sensor): # if door is closed
            if not (sensorTrigger):
                door_close() # fire GA code
                sensorTrigger = True # make sure it doesn't fire again

door_close_thread = threading.Thread(target=door_close)
door_close_thread.daemon =  True
door_close_thread.start()

Current_State  = 0
Previous_State = 0

try:
  print "Waiting for PIR to settle..."

  # Loop until PIR output is 0
  while GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR)==1:
    Current_State  = 0

  print "  Ready"

  while True :

    # Read PIR state
    Current_State = GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR)

    if Current_State==1 and Previous_State==0:
      # PIR is triggered
      print "  Motion detected!"
      # Record previous state
      Previous_State=1
    if not Current_State==0 and Previous_State==1:
      # PIR has returned to ready state
      print "  Ready"
      Previous_State=0

# Wait for 10 milliseconds
time.sleep(0.01)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print "  Quit"
  # Reset GPIO settings
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Your indenting is all wrong, this has many syntax errors that need fixing.

Comment: I can't even begin to try and fix your indentation here. Please read [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361) and ensure your code is correctly formatted.

Comment: I have corrected the indentation. sorry for the unseen mistakes. please help me to combine these two loops.

Comment: Why do you have an `except` with no `try`? Why do your two snippets have different indentation? Why don't you show the combined code that isn't working, not two separate loops?

Comment: i have compiled the two loops above. actually there is [try] to use with the [except] but at the end it's still not working. please correct me @jonrsharpe

Comment: @user3651467 of course it's not working; the first `for` loop never ends, so nothing below it ever happens

Comment: what do u mean @jonrsharpe ?i did not use for loop. is that mean that i need to change from while loop to for loop?

Comment: @user3651467 sorry, typo; `while True` is the fright choice to repeat indefinitely, but you need everything inside the one loop

Comment: okay @jonrsharpe . i got it already. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use two while loops.

The only way you'll break out of `while True:` is by calling `break`.

Use a single while loop and split it with if conditionals.

Comment: that's mean i need to combine into one while loop by putting the break in between the two separate commands. is it true?

Comment: You would put `break` when you need the loop to stop abruptly

Comment: i got it! the break really helps me. thanks so much for your help!